# Is it possible to send multiple commands in single plist - apple MDM protocol

Tags: ios, plist, mdm

We are developing an MDM for an enterprise solution. We were able to execute a few commands on the device and facing some challenges while developing a particular use case: To send multiple commands in Single plist.

We have tried with a few XML changes but there was an error, you can find XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Command</key>
        <dict>
            <key>RequestType</key>
            <string>DeviceLock</string>
        </dict>
        <key>CommandUUID</key>
        <string>543631bc-7030-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Command</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ManagementFlags</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>iTunesStoreID</key>
            <integer>1237819720</integer>
            <key>Options</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NotManaged</key>
                <boolean>true</boolean>
            </dict>
            <key>RequestType</key>
            <string>InstallApplication</string>
        </dict>
        <key>CommandUUID</key>
        <string>abcd</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. [According to the MDM Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/MDM-Protocol-Reference.pdf#c), you may only send one command at a time. Therefore it is necessary to create a queue of commands, and as the device makes these requests, remove the commands that have been `Acknowledged` and return the next command on the queue for that device.